# How can I join a Lubuntu machine to a Windows 2008 domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

I have a Lubuntu machine and I want to join it to a Windows domain. I've read that you need to download extra software to make this work, does anybody have any suggestion??

Comment: You need to include some information about what you have tried. What you have read that you think might be relevant. Any special requirements you have. And other things like that before your question is going to draw the responses and interest you need to get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerBroker. Download it here: http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/powerbroker-open-edition-evaluation/

You can find complete instructions here: http://www.testools.net/2013/10/how-to-add-linux-lubuntu-machine-to.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.